# Video set as background but space at top

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to add a background video to the menu of my app. However there is some space at the top. Not sure why that is.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/bgVideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? 
Also, is there any way to make the video dark. I have tried changing the aplha, but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: add more information

Answer (score 0):

In your java File. Assign Your Metrics Dynamically.

```
videoview= (VideoView)permit.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
videoview.setVideoURI(vidUri);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
vid_permit.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

videoview.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer tejas. However this solved the issue, not sure why though..

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```